# Error SQL72018: Database Options could not be imported

Tags: powershell, teamcity, octopus-deploy, dacpac

I am deploying an MVC Project along with a database using Octopus. When the step for deploying the database is hit I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.

 Error SQL72018: Database Options could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source.
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreateController(SqlDeployment deploymentEngine, ErrorManager errorManager)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object , Boolean , Object )
 Errors occurred while modeling the target database.  Deployment can not continue.
    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.ThrowIfErrors(String message, ErrorManager errors, Object category)
    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.OnLoad(ErrorManager errors, DeploymentEngineContext context)
    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.PrepareModels()
    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.InitializePlanGeneratator()
    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.CreateController(Action`1 msgHandler)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreateController(SqlDeployment deploymentEngine, ErrorManager errorManager)
```

Here's the Deploy.ps1 file

```
# Add the DLL
# For 64-bit machines
Write-Host "Add Types"
Add-Type -path ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll")
Add-Type -path ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll")


# Create the connection string
$services = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices ("Data Source=$dbSource;User Id=$dbAdminUser;Password=$dbAdminPassword")

Write-Host "Load the dacpac " + ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\Resources\Database.publish.xml")
#Load the dacpac
$dacpac = ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\Resources\Database.dacpac")
$dacpacoptions = ((Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName + "\Resources\Database.publish.xml")

#Load dacpac from file & deploy to database
$dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load($dacpac)

Write-Host "dacProfile set"
#Read a publish profile XML to get the deployment options
$dacProfile = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacProfile]::Load($dacpacoptions)

Write-Host "Add dbUser"
$dacProfile.DeployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues["dbUsername"] =  $dbUser
Write-Host "Add dbPassword"
$dacProfile.DeployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues["dbPassword"] = $dbPassword

Write-Host "About to deploy the dacpac"
# Deploy the dacpac
$services.Deploy($dp, $dbName, $TRUE, $dacProfile.DeployOptions)

# Configure IIS
.\DeployScripts\IISConfiguration.ps1
```

The SQL Project is aimed at SQL Server 2012. I'm not sure what other information would be helpful here, so let me know if you need more information. All help is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you checked the same by running SQLPackage.exe by providing required parameters. You might get actual error. Error looks like this Powershell is not able to take control on target database, it can be due to many reasons.. In one of my cases it was due to firewall as well.. You can try running SQLPackage.exe from that local machine as well..

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Package isn't installed on the servers I'm trying to deploy to, and I'm trying to avoid having to install it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to install SQLPackage they have released a NuGet package that contains it. Have a look here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Msbuild